# Taylor expansion upper bound

Tags: taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x > 0$ and let $c < 1$ be some constant. I am wondering: can I find an upper bound on $x$ such that
$$ e^{-x} + (1 - c)x < 1$$
which is a function of $c$? For instance, something like
$$x < 2c, \quad \text{ if } \quad c < \frac{1}{2}.$$
More generally, could people please point to relevant readings or places to learn more about this problem -- I am quite stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve analytically the equation
$$e^{-x} + (1 - c)x = 1$$ Its solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Skipping the steps, the solution is
$$x_*=\frac{1}{1-c}+W\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{c-1}}}{c-1}\right)$$ and the inequality holds for any $x < x_*$.

Close to $c=0$, using Taylor series, we have
$$x_*=2 c+\frac{4 c^2}{3}+\frac{10 c^3}{9}+\frac{136 c^4}{135}+O\left(c^5\right)$$

For almost the whole range, the Padé approximant
$$x_* \sim c \,\frac{2-\frac{16 }{11}c+\frac{32 }{495}c^2 } {1-\frac{46 }{33}c+\frac{67 }{165}c^2 }$$ seems to be quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^{-x}>0$ for any $x$. Therefore, we have 
$$(1-c)x<e^{-x} + (1 - c)x < 1,$$
which implies that 
$$x<\frac{1}{1-c}$$
since $c<1$. So we get an upper bound which is a function of $c$. But you may want some other bound.